# Pattern matching numeric strings

Tags: f#, pattern-matching

I have a function that pattern matches its argument, which is a `string`:

```
let processLexime lexime
    match lexime with
    | "abc" -> ...
    | "bar" -> ...
    | "cat" -> ...
    | _     -> ...
```

This works as expected. However, I'm now trying to extend this by expressing "match a `string` containing only the following characters". In my specific example, I want anything containing only digits to be matched.

My question is, how can I express this in F#? I'd prefer to do this without any libraries such as `FParsec`, since I'm mainly doing this for learning purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use active patterns: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233248.aspx

```
let (|Integer|_|) (str: string) =
   let mutable intvalue = 0
   if System.Int32.TryParse(str, &intvalue) then Some(intvalue)
   else None

let parseNumeric str =
   match str with
     | Integer i -> printfn "%d : Integer" i
     | _ -> printfn "%s : Not matched." str
```

Answer (score 2):

One way would be an active pattern

```
let (|Digits|_|) (s:string) = 
    s.ToCharArray() |> Array.forall (fun c -> System.Char.IsDigit(c)) |> function |true -> Some(s) |false -> None
```

then you can do

```
match "1" with
|Digits(t) -> printf "matched"
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use regular expressions combined with active patterns. With regular expressions you can easily match digits with `\d` and active patterns makes the syntax nice inside your `match`.

```
open System.Text.RegularExpressions

let (|ParseRegex|_|) regex str =
    let m = Regex("^"+regex+"$").Match(str)
    if (m.Success) then Some true else None

let Printmatch s =
    match s with
    | ParseRegex "w+" d -> printfn "only w"
    | ParseRegex "(w+|s+)+" d -> printfn "only w and s"
    | ParseRegex "\d+" d -> printfn "only digis"
    |_ -> printfn "wrong"

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    Printmatch "www"
    Printmatch "ssswwswwws"
    Printmatch "134554"
    Printmatch "1dwd3ddwwd"
    0
```

which prints

```
only w
only w and s
only digis
wrong
```